# How to cache the result of a Task when using it as an Observable with retry?

Tags: caching, task, system.reactive, reactive-programming

This is what I have:

```
CitiesObservable = Observable
                   .FromAsync(apiClient.GetCitiesTask)
                   .Retry();
```

`apiClient.GetCitiesTask` returns a task of type: `Task<List<City>>`

The problem is that every time I add a subscriber to the observable, apiClient.GetCitiesTask gets called again. How can I cache the result once it has completed successfully?

Thanks

**Question reworded**

I want apiClient.GetCitiesTask to be called as many times as needed (until it doesn't fail), but once it success, all late subscribers should use a cached result.

**Conclusion**

2 solutions arose, one I found and the other (the selected answer).

**Solution A:** (actually is almost a solution)

```
CitiesObservable = Observable.FromAsync(apiClient.GetCitiesTask).Publish();
CitiesObservable.Connect();
// Then you can subscribe as you want. But! you won't receive the cached value on late subscribers, only the onCompleted signal.
```

**Solution B:** (by @Bluesman)

```
CitiesObservable = Observable.StartAsync(
   () => Observable.FromAsync(apiClient.GetPlacesTask<City>).Retry().ToTask()
);
// Then you can subscribe as you want.
```

Comment: Actually, I think you want `PublishLast` because it replays the cached result to new observers. And you don't necessarily need to use `Connect`; you could instead use either `RefCount` or the `selector` overload (the latter is preferable in most cases).

Comment: @DaveSexton when using tasks, PublishLast or Publish wouldn't make a difference would they? (there is only 1 result). Could you give an example on how to use RefCount or selector?

Comment: Try it yourself. After receiving a notification, call `Subscribe` again on your `Publish`ed observable. Now, did you observe a cached notification again?
http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx

Comment: Just replace `Connect()` with `RefCount()`, though beware of its actual behavior. The `selector` overload probably isn't appropriate in this case, but it all depends upon what you're doing with the observable after connecting.

Comment: @DaveSexton, you're right I receive onCompleted on late subscribers, but no the value. I replaced Connect with RefCount(), but didn't work as expected. I will left only the other solution as the right one.

Comment: You need to use `PublishLast` instead of `Publish`, as I've already stated. `RefCount` is something entirely different - sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Note that the selected answer is just a longer way of doing `PublishLast`. Essentially, they amount to the same exact thing (namely, an `AsyncSubject`.)

Comment: @daveSexton I replaced publish with PublishLast and Connect with RefCount, but didn't work as expected. Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/laygr/5af5735a1f2b987a4de4 Maybe I got something wrong.

Comment: Know that `RefCount` will cause your async method to be invoked every time the observer count goes from 0 to 1. It might not be what you want - it was just a suggestion. You need to be aware of the actual semantics of the operators that you choose :)

Comment: `RefCount` returns an observable and you didn't subscribe to it. Look at the signature.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks a lot. I know there's a learning curve and im not done with it. I'll check your blog post.

Comment: If you want to use solution A for any reason, you can fix it by replacing Publish() with Replay(1).

Comment: Sigh, just use `PublishLast`. Even `Replay(1)` is more complicated than is necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about....

```
Observable
    .StartAsync(() => Observable
        .FromAsync(reserbusAPI.GetPlacesTask<City>)
        .Retry()
        .ToTask());
```

The outer `StartAsync` makes sure the eventual result from the created task is buffered while the inner `FromAsync` with `Retry` makes sure that `GetPlacesTask` is called as many times as needed. However, the whole retrying-thing still starts even before the first subscription.

Comment: As long as late subscribers get the cached result, it would be what im looking; I don't need it to be lazy. I'll check in about an hour.